# Unrecognized FaultException when Connecting to RemoteAgent

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dottrace

How can I troubleshoot the following error message in the dotTrace Profiler Configuration dialog?

```
Unrecognized FaultException: code Receiver, prefix Server was 
unable to process request. ---> Unable to open f
```

I have a RemoteAgent configured and running on a server, firewall port 9000 open.

Attempting to connect to it, I specify the IP address, port, and endpoint and I get the message above.  That is it...it ends with the letter "f" and I'm not sure what it is referring to.  I checked the logs, unfortunately, this is all I'm getting:

```
12:51:09 PM.060: Thread:1: [ConfigRemove] #13 HostParameters:
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HostParameters type="RemoteHostParameters">
    <Domain IsNull="False">
    </Domain>
    <Password IsNull="False">
    </Password>
    <Url>http://192.168.1.177:9000/RemoteAgent/AgentService.asmx</Url>
    <UserName IsNull="False">
    </UserName>
</HostParameters>
12:51:09 PM.060: Thread:1: [ConfigRemove] #13 Make selection empty
12:51:09 PM.590: Thread:1: [ConfigActivate] #14 HostParameters:
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HostParameters type="RemoteHostParameters">
    <Domain IsNull="False">
    </Domain>
    <Password IsNull="False">
    </Password>
    <Url>http://192.168.1.177:9000/RemoteAgent/AgentService.asmx</Url>
    <UserName IsNull="False">
    </UserName>
</HostParameters>
12:51:09 PM.590: Thread:1: [ConfigActivate] #14 Set selection
12:51:09 PM.876: Thread:1: [ConfigActivate] #14 Start processing
12:51:09 PM.877: Thread:40: [ConfigActivate] #14 Connecting
12:51:09 PM.880: Thread:40: Local SysTools v5.5.4.160 loaded
12:51:10 PM.674: Thread:40: [ConfigActivate] #14 Failed
12:51:10 PM.674: Thread:40: [ConfigActivate] #14 Stored
12:51:10 PM.674: Thread:40: [ConfigActivate] #14 Set selection
```

There doesn't seem to be any information on the server either. All I see in the event log is the following, which is logged on startup of RemoteAgent but makes sense as it likely doesn't want itself to be profiled:

```
The profiler has requested that the CLR instance not load 
the profiler into this process.
```

There are no other log files or artifacts that I can find.

Other info:

- I'm on Windows 8.1
- dotTrace version is 5.5.4
- Server is 2012
- All apps run with admin privileges

I have been able to connect to other RemoteAgents on other servers. Don't know what the missing piece is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this, the fix is pretty simple.  There were, at one point, more than one version of the RemoteAgent deployed to the server.

I deleted the files in the following folder (thanks to a response on the JetBrains forum from Ilya Chernikov):
%ProgramData%\JetBrains\Profiler\RemoteAgent\SysToolsCache

I then redeployed the current version of RemoteAgent to the server. When I connected, the caches were restored and I was able to connect.

Comment: I had to delete files from C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Profiler as well